# Win11: Task manager's cpu usage discrepancy

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

The discrepency is between the two views:

The 'Details' view shows **a process** as taking 11%.
System idle is 80%.

The 'Processes' view shows **the same process** as taking 70%.
Total cpu usage is 80%.